# confused on Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(1-z)},\qquad 0 < |z| < 1$

at first the function is analytic.

then, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z(1-z)}$ due to partial fraction decomposition it becomes $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{1-z}$

this is where I become confused.

When doing $0 <|z|$:

there is no Taylor series, is that right?

Now for $|z| < 1$:

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ stays the same, and for $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is turned into geometric series which is $\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$

so the final result is $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$? So is it correctly done right...or I am doing it fully wrong.

Comment: You have got the right answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks...I have one more question for $|z| <1$ why 1/x stays the same and doesn't change?

Comment: @EM4 Because it's a Laurent series at 0. All terms are of the form $a_n z^n$. Centered at another point $z_0$, they would be $a_n (z-z_0)^n$